# Периодическое зависание Apache

Tags: php, apache, oracle

Каждый день где-то в 17:48 сайт начинает работать очень медленно, - точнее происходит долгое ожидание ответов на запросы к БД (стоит Oracle 11g). На web-сервере стоит Apache и ситуацию с сайтом  поправляет его перезагрузка.
   В логах Apache и php ничего подозрительного не нашла, задач в автозагрузке и cron на это время нет, БД в это время доступна.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?  Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может служить причиной ее возникновения?

Comment: А что за запрос? Он до Oracle  вообще доходит? В списке активных сессий видно его? Быть может запрос чего то ждет. Коммита там какого нибудь от другого запроса из Apache ?

Comment: Это просто запрос на выборку данных из таблицы. Насчет сессий точно не знаю, сегодня вечером проверю. Меня смущает, что  зависает в одно и тоже время, когда  пользователей на сайте мало. Если ничего не делать, на следующий день все снова начинает работать. Если бы проблема была в коммите, то после перезагрузки Apache она бы, наверное,  осталась, но  сайт после этого  начинает работать.

Comment: Может сама БД в это время производит какие-то проверки/оптимизации/и т..д (к сожалению, не знаком с Oracle, просто предположение).

Comment: А в запросе на выборку в конце не прописано в конце `for update` ?. Думаю стоит посмотреть на стороне БД, из-за чего виснет запрос и виснет ли вообще. Если у вас есть DBA, то попросите их разобраться. Очень сложно диагностировать проблемы "по фотографии".

Comment: Еще как идея. Возможно именно в это время запускаются какие нибудь бэкапы или другие задачи с БД по расписанию. Об это тоже следует спросить администраторов БД.

Comment: Думаю, что тогда бы медленно обрабатывались запросы в Toad,  но этого не происходит. Спрашивала админа, он утверждает, что на это время никах задач на выполнение  не стоит

Comment: а что значит "медленно обрабатывались" ? Вы посмотрите, как будет ваш конкретный запрос обрабатываться.

Comment: Я запускала этот же  запрос в Toad, в это время и он нормально обрабатывался. На сайте он очень долго ждет ответ и сваливается по Timeout(( Но после перезагрузки Apache все опять начинает работать

Comment: Если запрос идет по сети, то возможно это какая то сетевая проблема. В любом случае предлагаю начать с того, чтобы исследовать сессию которую открывает ваш Apachce к Oracle и исследовать причину, по которой он работает так долго. Посмотреть, с какими параметрами запускается и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо за совет) сегодня  вечером проверю сессию.  Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно проверить, если это сетевая проблема?

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу ничего подсказать по сетям. Тут я не компетентен. Самым разумным будет локализовать проблему и дальше передать ее нужным специалистам внутри вашей компании